# I need help to find surface area of the function $\operatorname e^{-3x}$ within interval $[0, 7]$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

Can you someone give me a hint to start finding the surface area of the function $f(x) = e^{-3x}$ within interval $[0, 7]$? like which method I should choose ?
I tried find area by the following integral:

$$\int_{x=0}^{x=7} 2\pi \operatorname e^{-3x}\sqrt{1+9\operatorname e^{-6x}}\, \operatorname dx$$

Update:
I substitute
$\tan(\theta) = \operatorname e^{-3x}$
$\sec(\theta) = \sqrt{1+9 \operatorname e^{-6x}}$  and
I got answer as below
$\pi[(\sqrt{1+9\operatorname e^{-6x}}\operatorname e^{-3x}+\ln(|\sqrt{1+9e^{-6x}}|+\operatorname e^{-3x}))]|_0^7$
but that gives negative number as area. I think I made wrong somewhere, but unable to figure out what it is, please if you anyone tell me the write way, it will be great help.

Comment: What went wrong when you were trying to evaluate that integral?

Comment: That looks like the right integral to me, by the way--it is an integral that you can evaluate.

Comment: actually, I don't the correct way to integrate this, that's my issue? can u tell me the correct substitution to use for this integral, please?

Comment: @user114408: Tell me if I screwed up the formatting.

Comment: Surface of what? the cylinder?

Comment: @nbubis: the surface area for f(x) = $e^{-3x}$ revolve around x-axis between interval [0,7]

Comment: If you put the stuff you are taking the square root of in braces, it will all be under the square root sign.  So \sqrt{1+9e^{-6x}} gives $\sqrt{1+9e^{-6x}}$  Also putting backslashes before functions gives the proper font:  \tan gives $\tan$

Comment: The question makes no sense without the phrase "revolve around the $x$-axis" somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If $\tan \theta = e^{-3x}$, then $\sec \theta =\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \theta}=\sqrt {1+e^{-6x}}$.  You probably want $\tan \theta = 3e^{-3x}$

Comment: I got you. thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @user114408 Clicking the green pipe you can accept an answer, which is a big reward to the answerer.